# Why does my program calculates results infinitely or an inproper number of times when given unproper input?

Tags: c, loops, infinite

The default input in this program is "number operator" fe. "43 +". When I type in a letter instead of a number or two or more letters instead of an operator it produces results infinitely when AFAIK it should produce just one meaningless result and stop.

When I type in two (or more) operators instead of one fe. "--" it does run the calculation twice (or more). The variable the operator is saved in is a char, so only one operator should be taken in.

I want to understand why does this happen. It's not explained in the book I'm using, at least so far.

The full code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float number;
    char operator;
    _Bool terminate = 0;
    float accumulator = 0;

    printf ("Begin Calculations\n");

    while (terminate == 0) {
        scanf ("%f %c", &number, &operator);
        printf ("number %.6f      operator %c\n", number, operator);

        if (operator == '+') {
            accumulator += number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == '-') {
            accumulator -= number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == '*') {
            accumulator *= number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == '/') {
            if (number == 0) {
                printf ("You can't divide by zero.\n");
            }    
            else {
                accumulator /= number;
                printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
            }
        }
        else if (operator == 'S') {
            accumulator = number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == 'E') {
            printf ("= %.6f\nEnd of Calculations.\n", accumulator);
            terminate = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
        }    
    } 
return 0;    
}
```

Comment: you should check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: it loops because 'terminate' is never updated.   After this line: '      printf ("Unknown operator.\n");' insert this line: 'terminate = 1;''

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are trying to scan a number. Anything else than number causes undefined behavior, which is exactly what you're experiencing.

To avoid that, check that you have scanned *something* by checking the return value of scanf:

```
retval = scanf ("%f %c", &number, &operator);
```

If `retval == 0`, whatever was given is not the correct string and will possibly cause undefined behaviour. With that knowledge, another while loop could be used to scanf until you have a valid input.

The fix is a bit more difficult because scanf doesn't flush the input buffer, and will therefore start looping itself. In order to solve that, you need some kind of buffer flush mechanism. An example supplied below simply reads the buffer via getchar until eol or eof, clearing the buffer for future input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float number;
    char operator;
    _Bool terminate = 0;
    float accumulator = 0;
    int c;

    printf ("Begin Calculations\n");

    while (terminate == 0) {
        while (scanf("%f %c", &number, &operator) != 2) {
            printf("Incorrect input\n");
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }

        printf ("number %.6f      operator %c\n", number, operator);

        if (operator == '+') {
            accumulator += number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == '-') {
            accumulator -= number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == '*') {
            accumulator *= number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == '/') {
            if (number == 0) {
                printf ("You can't divide by zero.\n");
            }
            else {
                accumulator /= number;
                printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
            }
        }
        else if (operator == 'S') {
            accumulator = number;
            printf ("= %.6f\n", accumulator);
        }
        else if (operator == 'E') {
            printf ("= %.6f\nEnd of Calculations.\n", accumulator);
            terminate = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is that way because programming languages strive to meet specifications in the most precise way. The space of valid inputs is strictly limited while the space of invalid inputs is infinite - handling every possible case is close to impossible. The scanf actually acts as expected: it tries to scan the values from stdin but does not remove them if they don't meet the specification - your code could react further to the same input if it doesn't pass.